# Django Template Tags in Views

Tags: django, django-templates

Hi I need to refresh my custom template tag --right_side.py-- via Ajax. Is there a way to import the template tag in the view and return it as HttpResponse because I don't want to give up my custom template tag (it works great in other pages) nor code a new view action which is really similar to it.

Having a link to call with Ajax or loading it in the view inside

if request.isAjax():

Are both fine for me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I find it really useful when refreshing an area with ajax. So thought it would be good to share it:

First you import the custom template tag you coded in your view file.

```
from your_app_name.templatetags import your_tag_name
```

And then you use it like this:

```
return HttpResponse(your_tag_name.your_method(context))
```

That worked for me and I got the template tag as response from server and refreshed the div with that result.

Answer (score 11):

I had this same question awhile ago,  I was loading HTML snippets with AJAX which I had already written as template tags.  And I was trying to avoid duplicating the code in two places.

This is what I came up with to render a template tag from a view (called via ajax):

```
from django.template import RequestContext, Template

def myview(req):
   context = RequestContext({'somearg':"FooBarBaz"})

   template_string = """
      {% load my_tag from tagsandfilters %}
      {% my_tag somearg %}
   """

   t = Template(template_string)
   return HttpResponse(t.render(context))
```

Comment: This doesn't actually invoke the middleware properly.  Calls to `{% csrf %}` in the template associated w/ my templatetag come up blank.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13241278/calling-a-templatetag-from-a-view-csrf-not-gtting-populated  Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Need to make the context a RequestContext.  `context = RequestContext(request, {....})`

Comment: I wanted to use the template tag in a utils function and the RequestContext kept causing an error due to it expecting a request object. A plain `Context`did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a template just containing your templatetag and nothing else. Then you would have in right_side.html:

```
{%load cems_templatetags%}
{%right_side%}
```

and in the view something like:

```
if request.isAjax():
  return render_to_response('right_side.html',RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Yes, but if you have to additional work to prepare the variables needed by the template, then you have to duplicate the code in both places.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution :

```
from templatetags_file_name import my_templatetag
return render (request,'path/to/template.html', my_templatetag(parameter) )
```

And, in my "templatetags_file_name", "my_templatetag" is like that :

```
@register.inclusion_tag('path/to/template.html') 
def my_templatetag(parameter):
    #my operations
    return locals()
```