# Calling a templatetag from a view -- CSRF not gtting populated

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I am using inclusion_tags to generate portions of my pages that repeat in many different places across my site.

templatetags/tags.py

```
@register.inclusion_tag('chunk_template.html')
def output_chunk(object, edit):
    ... # Lots of set up work here that I don't want to duplicate in the view
    return { ... }
```

Upon AJAX submit of a form on the page, I need to refresh the very same HTML outputted by output_chunk().  To avoid completely rewriting output_chunk() in a view, [I did the following as recommended in this answer about how to use templatetags in views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5068272/django-template-tags-in-views):

views.py

```
def chunk(request, ...):
    context = Context({..., 'request': request })
    template_string = """
      {% load output_chunk from tags %}
      {% output_chunk ... %}
    """
    t = Template(template_string)
    return HttpResponse(t.render(context))
```

This is all working fine, except chunk_template.html calls `{% csrf %}`, which works when I call the template tag the standard way, but not when I call in this somewhat hacky way (to avoid writing the same code twice).

(For simpler template tags, this works fine when I call `return render (request, template_name, context)` from within the view.)

So, is there a better way to call the template tag from within the view to get all the middleware invoked properly?  Or is there something I can add to this hack to make it work properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to make the context a RequestContext.

```
context = RequestContext(request, {....})
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand the core of the problem, but you can always manually pull the token (the middleware calls this function).

```
from django.middleware.csrf import get_token

csrf = get_token(request)
```

Comment: Ahhh, useful shortcut.  But I think I figured out what the issue was -- I need to call make the context a RequestContext (`RequestContext(request, {...})`) in order to invoke the middleware.  I still wonder if there isn't a better way to call a templatetag from a view, though...  This all seems very hacky.

Comment: Well the template tag has the context with {% csrf_token %} - if you render a string, it has no such context.

Comment: True, but I see now that if I call `HttpResponse(t.render(context))` on that same string if I make context a `RequestContext` and not a regular `Context` then it now has the context.

Comment: Indeed! I'm glad you found a solution.