# Calling django template tags from a normal function

Tags: python, django

How to call django template tags from a normal function?

For instance:

**Django template tag:**

```
@register.filter(name='CallingTemplateTagFunction')
def CallingTemplateTagFunction(price):    
    return price*10/100
```

I wanna to call GetValue function in a normal function.

For instance:

**Normal python function:**

```
def Test(request):
    CallingTemplateTagFunction(50) # How to call django template tag function?
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django Template Tags in Views](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5068272/django-template-tags-in-views)

Comment: Have you tried that exact code? There's no reason it wouldn't work.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I am confused how to call template tags in a normal function

Comment: You do it *just like you have shown*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can write somewhere your function:

```
def my_useful_function(price):
    return price * 10 / 100
```

And then use it in your views and in template tags:

```
from somewhere import my_useful_function

# in templatetags:    
@register.filter(name='calling_template_tag_function')
def calling_template_tag_function(price):    
    return my_useful_function(price)
```

And then in views:

```
def test(request):
   my_useful_function(50)
```

Comment: Please follow the basic naming conventions: Use the function naming rules: lowercase with words separated by underscores as necessary to improve readability.  Class names should normally use the CapWords convention. Source: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: @guettli I totally agree with that, but while answering I was following the author's question style - it is easier to understand answer, without distracting mind with other contexts and problems.

But, good point for vamsi to check PEP's and follow it during writing python code.

Thanks for your comment!

Comment: Remember that answers are not just "for one person", but "for everyone who finds an answer in the future". Don't match their style if their style does not follow the established conventions: write proper code so that every future visitor finds a proper answer instead of one showing extremely questionable code =) At best, you can tell someone that they can adapt the code to match their own style, but telling them that their code needs to use proper python conventions as part of your answer is perfectly acceptable.